# Biztalk Schema for missing values

Tags: biztalk, biztalk-2013r2

I have a biztalk 2013-r2 schema for a txt file, that sometimes does not have a value for the last column.

```
With value:
Name, address, city, state, zip, phone
Mike Myers, 30 West Street, NY, 10001, 2124444444

Without value:
Name, address, city, state, zip, phone
Mike Myers, 30 West Street, NY, 10001,
```

When the column has value, there are no issues.

When the last column has no value, I get the following error:

```
PublicKeyToken=92c4a30afea05f3e" Source: "Flat file disassembler" Receive Port: "rp_List" URI: "C:\BiztalkTestFiles\List\myfiles\*.txt" Reason: Unexpected data found while looking for:
'\r\n'
The current definition being parsed is Mydefinition. The stream offset where the error occured is 101. The line number where the error occured is 2. The column where the error occured is 6.
```

**Is there a workaround for this type of issue?**

Schema attached:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<xs:schema xmlns="http://usgeSales.ldcSyncList.schemas.MySchema" xmlns:b="http://schemas.microsoft.com/BizTalk/2003" targetNamespace="http://usgeSales.ldcSyncList.schemas.MySchema" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xs:annotation>
    <xs:appinfo>
      <schemaEditorExtension:schemaInfo namespaceAlias="b" extensionClass="Microsoft.BizTalk.FlatFileExtension.FlatFileExtension" standardName="Flat File" xmlns:schemaEditorExtension="http://schemas.microsoft.com/BizTalk/2003/SchemaEditorExtensions" />
      <b:schemaInfo standard="Flat File" codepage="65001" default_pad_char=" " pad_char_type="char" count_positions_by_byte="false" parser_optimization="speed" lookahead_depth="3" suppress_empty_nodes="false" generate_empty_nodes="true" allow_early_termination="false" early_terminate_optional_fields="false" allow_message_breakup_of_infix_root="false" compile_parse_tables="false" root_reference="MySchema" />
    </xs:appinfo>
  </xs:annotation>
  <xs:element name="MySchema">
    <xs:annotation>
      <xs:appinfo>
        <b:recordInfo structure="delimited" child_delimiter_type="hex" child_delimiter="0xD 0xA" child_order="postfix" sequence_number="1" preserve_delimiter_for_empty_data="true" suppress_trailing_delimiters="false" />
      </xs:appinfo>
    </xs:annotation>
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:annotation>
          <xs:appinfo>
            <groupInfo sequence_number="0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/BizTalk/2003" />
          </xs:appinfo>
        </xs:annotation>
        <xs:element maxOccurs="unbounded" name="MySchema_Detail">
          <xs:annotation>
            <xs:appinfo>
              <b:recordInfo structure="delimited" child_delimiter_type="char" child_delimiter="," child_order="infix" sequence_number="1" preserve_delimiter_for_empty_data="true" suppress_trailing_delimiters="false" />
            </xs:appinfo>
          </xs:annotation>
          <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
              <xs:annotation>
                <xs:appinfo>
                  <groupInfo sequence_number="0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/BizTalk/2003" />
                </xs:appinfo>
              </xs:annotation>
              <xs:element name="Name" type="xs:string">
                <xs:annotation>
                  <xs:appinfo>
                    <b:fieldInfo justification="left" sequence_number="1" />
                  </xs:appinfo>
                </xs:annotation>
              </xs:element>
              <xs:element name="Address" type="xs:string">
                <xs:annotation>
                  <xs:appinfo>
                    <b:fieldInfo justification="left" sequence_number="2" />
                  </xs:appinfo>
                </xs:annotation>
              </xs:element>
              <xs:element name="State" type="xs:string">
                <xs:annotation>
                  <xs:appinfo>
                    <b:fieldInfo justification="left" sequence_number="3" />
                  </xs:appinfo>
                </xs:annotation>
              </xs:element>
              <xs:element name="Zip" type="xs:string">
                <xs:annotation>
                  <xs:appinfo>
                    <b:fieldInfo justification="left" sequence_number="4" />
                  </xs:appinfo>
                </xs:annotation>
              </xs:element>
              <xs:element maxOccurs="0" name="Phone" type="xs:string">
                <xs:annotation>
                  <xs:appinfo>
                    <b:fieldInfo justification="left" sequence_number="5" />
                  </xs:appinfo>
                </xs:annotation>
              </xs:element>
            </xs:sequence>
          </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

file 1: with.txt

```
Mike Myers, 30 West Street, NY, 10001, 2124444444
```

file 2: without.txt

```
Mike Myers, 30 West Street, NY, 10001,
```

Comment: Please add your schema to the question and give us the exact samples you are using.

Comment: I added schema and files

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually you simply set the Min Occurs on the last element to 0

Also make sure that your records do actually finish with a CR & LF (use NotePad++ and show All Symbols)

The fact that it is complaining on line 2 column 11, your problem may actually be something else.

Comment: I used notepad++ and it says CR LF

Comment: I did max occur and it did not work. I have attached the schema to the question.

Error 1 Unexpected data found while looking for:
'\r\n'
The current definition being parsed is MySchema_Detail. The stream offset where the error occured is 31. The line number where the error occured is 1. The column where the error occured is 31. C:\BiztalkTestFiles\ldcSyncList\without.txt 1 1

Comment: Did you get it working?  You marked my answer as the answer.  I just tried it with your schema and the samples and it works.  I did make one typo in my answer which I will correct, it should be Min Occurs = 0 rather than Max Occurs, Max occurs can be left blank (defaults 1) or set to 1